# Use copy() to populate an immutable field

Tags: kotlin

I have a data class with 3 fields on val type.

```
data class Person(
    val id: UUID? = null,
    val name: String,
    val address: String?
)
```

I have a Family class which contains :

```
    val familyId: UUID? = null,
    val pList: List<Person>
```

In one of the other classes I have to iterate over the `pList` BUT I need to change the address field for the person while fetching it from another map, based on the id.

I know I can use `copy()` method to populate an immutable field but I am not sure how to do it exactly. I was trying something like this but I doesn’t seem to work.

```
family.pList.forEach {
    it.copy(address = ‘I am getting this value from a map’ )
}
```

I thought address would get populated with the new value but it’s not.

Note also the address field in the pList is not populated.

Comment: The way you are copying it is correct, but you are not using the new value returned from the copy call, so it is just doing nothing. You need to assign the result of the copy call to something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `copy` function returns a new instance of the object with the fields populated as provided when calling `copy`. So you need to save the new objects somewhere. Your method, as written, is creating a copied object and essentially discarding it immediately.

Here's what I would do:

```
val withAddresses = family.pList.map {
    it.copy(address = "I am getting this value from a map")
}
```

The new variable, withAddresses, references the list of Person objects with the address field populated.

Comment: So I kind of need to take this `withAddress` and populate the family object with it ? What I am not getting is that in my case i have a `forEach`

Comment: Your code in `forEach` doesn't do anything with the result. It makes a copy, then throws it away by not assigning it to anything. `map` is like `forEach` except the final value is added to a new list.

Comment: Ok, I get that. But what I am not getting is how to put that thing in the family object back again as I want to update the same family object and fields list type is `VAL`?

Comment: If you want to be able to modify the list, it needs to be `MutableList`, not just a `List`. `map` always returns a brand new List. I'm surprised the stdlib doesn't have a `mapInPlace` function, but you can write your own: `inline fun <T> MutableList<T>.mapInPlace(transform: (T) -> T): MutableList<T> { for (i in indices) { this[i] = transform(this[i]) }; return this }`

Comment: exactly my point. The list is an immutable list. One work around I can think of is return a list and then use `copy()` on the Family object itself to populate the list and then save it to the repository. But I am not sure if that's a correct thing to do. Though it works just fine.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to fix it the same way as I explained the "work around" in the previous comment. Thanks to everyone for the prompt help ! @Tenfour04